# Interface proxy without inheriting attributes

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

When creating an interface proxy using [Castle DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md), it seems that the created proxy object always “inherits” the attributes of the interface.

In general, this is not a real problem, but in my case, I’m using the proxy to generate a WCF service implementation at run-time. The interface has a [`ServiceContractAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx), and WCF really does not like it when the implementing type (the service *behavior*) has that attribute as well.

See the following example:

```
var generator = new ProxyGenerator();

var interceptor = new ExampleInterceptor();
var proxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(typeof(ITest), interceptor);

proxy.GetType().CustomAttributes.Select(a => a.AttributeType.Name).Dump();
// SerializableAttribute, XmlIncludeAttribute, ServiceContractAttribute 

typeof(Test).CustomAttributes.Select(a => a.AttributeType.Name).Dump();
// (empty)
```

```
public class ExampleInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) { }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest { }

public class Test : ITest { }
```

When looking at the proxy type’s attributes, I get the following *three*: `SerializableAttribute`, `XmlIncludeAttribute`, and `ServiceContractAttribute`. So not only does DP copy the `ServiceContractAttribute`, it also adds two more (I don’t really care about those). If I compare that to a manual implementation of my interface, I don’t get any types.

So there *is* something in DP that actually adds those attributes. Is there any way to influence that attribute generation, to stop DP from adding the interface’s attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AttributesToAvoidReplicating` to avoid specific attributes replication:

```
AttributesToAvoidReplicating.Add<ServiceContractAttribute>();
```

Comment: Hah, that’s an unbelivably telling name! I’m not perfectly happy with it being static but since I don’t ever want to replicate a service contract attribute, this works well enough for me. Thanks a lot! Do you happen to know if there’s another fine-grained way to impact this on a per-proxy level?

Comment: @poke, You'll have to provide your own `ProxyBuilder` that internally uses its own custom `Generator` that will have to provide a custom  `InterfaceProxyWithoutTargetGenerator` implementation. Pretty awkward.